# Showing independence of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

The problem is here
[image]

The trouble im having is showing how $\bar{x}-\bar{y}$ is independent of $S_{pool}$. I know the covariance of ( $\bar{x}-\bar{y}$,$X_i-\bar{x}$)=0 and similarly for the other case. But I don't know how to show that  $\bar{x}-\bar{y}$ is independent of $s_{pool}$? I know that $s_{pool}=\dfrac{1}{(m+n-2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{3(m-1)s_x^2+(n-1)s_y^2}$ and it follows that $(\bar{x},s_x^2)$ and $(\bar{y},s_y^2)$ are independent of one another. But not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variables $\bar{X}-\bar{Y}\,,\,\, X_i-\bar{X}$ and $Y_i-\bar{Y}$ are jointly (and marginally) normal, since they are linear combinations of independent, Normally distributed, random variables. Consequently, [a well known property of Multivariate Gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)  guarantees that 
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{C}ov\left(\bar{X}-\bar{Y}\,,\, X_i-\bar{X}\right){}={}0&{}\implies{}&\,\,\bar{X}-\bar{Y}\,\mbox{and}\,\, X_i-\bar{X}\mbox{ are independent}\,.\newline
\mathbb{C}ov\left(\bar{X}-\bar{Y}\,,\, X_i-\bar{X}\right){}={}0&{}\implies{}&\,\,\bar{X}-\bar{Y}\,\mbox{and}\,\, Y_i-\bar{Y}\mbox{ are independent}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Therefore, as a function of $X_i-\bar{X}$ and $Y_i-\bar{Y}$, $s_{pool}$ is independent of $\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$.